# plpgsql trigger shows value as exists when is not

Tags: postgresql, triggers, pgadmin-4

My tables are

```
CREATE TABLE historia_alumno(
period varchar(5) NOT NULL,
no_control varchar(9) NOT NULL,
mater varchar(7) NOT NULL,
calif int
primary key(no_control,mater)
);
```

as unique condition; also

```
CREATE TABLE seleccion_mater(
period varchar(5) NOT NULL,
no_control varchar(9) NOT NULL,
mater varchar(7) NOT NULL
primary key(period,no_control,mater)
);
```

with unique condition.
If ever looks similar, has different scenarios; my trigger function was created with pgadmin4 and is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION alta_materia()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE
    COST 100
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM historia_alumno HA WHERE HA.no_control=NEW.no_control AND HA.mater=NEW.mater AND HA.calif>=70)THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Student has approved previously assignment';
    ROLLBACK;
    RETURN NULL;
ELSE 
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM seleccion_mater SM WHERE SM.period=NEW.period AND SM.no_control=NEW.no_control AND SM.mater=NEW.mater)THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Student has assignment in their list of to_do ';
    ROLLBACK;
    RETURN NULL;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$;
```

This function is activated before insert in table seleccion_mater.
WITHOUT insert any value, and as a check point, i've done the follow (in pgadmin4)

```
do $$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM seleccion_mater SM WHERE SM.period='20221' and SM.no_control='17760218' AND SM.materi='05ISC04') THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Exists';
ELSE
    RAISE NOTICE 'Not exists';
END IF;
END $$;
```

Output is "Not exists", and that is correct because the table is empty; but, if i now do

```
INSERT INTO seleccion_mater(period,no_control,mater) VALUES('20221','17760218','05ISC04');
```

Result is

> Error: Student has assignment in their list of to_do
> When value is not present in the table.
> I've also change the trigger function as follow

```
DECLARE
yeap integer:=0;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO yeap FROM seleccion_mater SM WHERE SM.period=NEW.period AND SM.no_control=NEW.no_control AND SM.mater=NEW.mater;
IF yeap>0 THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Student has assignment in their to_do list %',yeap;
```

And then, trying to do insert again with previously values as before, the output is now

> Student has assignment in their to_do list 1
> I don't known why is counting a value the trigger function, when is not present.

Comment: What's the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement? I bet it's an `AFTER` trigger, right? Well, that does "see" the changes done by the triggering statement (for that row). But checking if the primary key values already exists to throw an error if they do is pretty pointless here. The implicit unique constraint will handle that already.

Comment: Also, your trigger function can never run, since it contains `ROLLBACK`. Perhaps you should show your real code; it may be that your simplifications obliterated the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the support. When a trigger function is created using pgadmin4, the first step is create the trigger function (as show previously). To invoke this (as second step) is right click the table and under Triggers, call the function previously created. and there is where user defined is going to be used in insert (after or before), etc. Pgadmin do the rest.